# How to save value of the new column in the “sales_flat_quote_item” for order decline remarks?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, forms, table, column

I created  a new column in `sales_flat_quote_item` named `itemcomment`. i want to to insert textbox value this column.

my form .....`comment.phtml`

```
<form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline');?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" id="decline" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>"/>
  </form>
```

**CustomercartController.php**

```
public function remarksdeclineAction()
{

           $message =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
           //echo $message;
           $quoteItem  = Mage::getModel('orderapproval/quoteitem');
          $quoteItem->setItemcomment($message);
         $quoteItem->save();
}
```

**controller is calling with echo**

Model/Orderapproval.php

```
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

{
    public function _construct() {
        $this->_init('zetaprints_orderapproval/quoteitem','item_id');
    }

}
```

**Model/Resource/Orderapproval.php**

```
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('zetaprints_orderapproval/quoteitem','item_id');
    }

}
```

**Model/Resource/Orderapproval/Collection.php**

```
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource_OrderApproval_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('zetaprints_orderapproval/quoteitem');
    }
}
```

**config.xml**

```
 <models>
      <zetaprints_orderapproval>
        <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>zetaprints_orderapproval_resource</resourceModel>
      </zetaprints_orderapproval>
      <zetaprints_orderapproval_resource>
                <class>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Resource</class>
                 <entities>
                    <quoteitem>
                        <table>sales_flat_quote_item</table>
                    </quoteitem>
                </entities>
            </zetaprints_orderapproval_resource>
      <sales>
        <rewrite>
          <quote>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Quote</quote>
        </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </models>


<resources>
      <orderapproval_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>ZetaPrints_OrderApproval</module>
          <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </orderapproval_setup>

      <orderapproval_write>
        <connection><use>core_write</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_write>

      <orderapproval_read>
        <connection><use>core_read</use></connection>
      </orderapproval_read>
    </resources>
```

but **i am getting Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function `setItemcomment()` on boolean

**table name:** sales_flate_quote_item 
**column name:** itemcomment

Thanks.

Comment: anyone can help me i am very stuck about this query

Answer (score 0):

You have to call event and a method on that event like :

```
<events>
    <sales_quote_item_set_product>
        <observers>
        <YOUR_MODULE>
            <class>YOUR_MODULE/observer</class>
            <method>your_method_name</method>
        </YOUR_MODULE>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_set_product>
</events>
```

Your observer file :

```
<?php
class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Observer
{

    public function your_method_name(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $valueToset = $product->getAttributeValue(); // or any value which you want to set
        $item->setCustomField($valueToset); // here your db field name is "custom_field"
        //You can also use $item->setData('field_name',$valueToset);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not get you

Comment: i have added event in config.xml and method in controller

Comment: getAttributeValue(); is $message am i right

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari, no, you have to add method in model file like `model/observer` which class is already mention in event area

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari, you can set any value in $message

Comment: can you write observer.php file for me please

Comment: please help me i am searching for last one month for this query

Comment: i am getting same error

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari, Pl check my updated answer. Also if this resolve your issue then mark as accepted. As we notice that you are not accepting any once answer if it resolves your issue.

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari, Whats the error ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setItemcomment() on boolean

Comment: class ZetaPrints_OrderApproval_Model_Observer
{

    public function item_comment(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $message =  $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $valueToset = $product->$message; // or any value which you want to set
        $item->setItemcomment($valueToset); // here your db field name is "custom_field"
        //You can also use $item->setData('field_name',$valueToset);
        return $this;
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50885/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-ashish-jagnani).

Comment: i did not get solution and you check and reply me